# iOS: is it possible to make table view header section width bigger than tableview width itself?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there a way for a table view header section to have a bigger width then the actual table? Here's a simple picture that shows what I mean:

[image]

Basically, I need to make the header section to extend beyond the small table view.

Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to archive? Will the TableView fill the width of the view? Would narrowing the cells instead do the trick? Will you target iPhone or iPad? Could the new collection view in ios6 solve your problem?

Comment: The tableview is pretty small so it's way less then the full width of the window. Narrowing the cells may do the trick... so far that's the only way that kinda makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is subclassing UITableCell and overriding setFrame method.